# How to await a specific prop change in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to code a notification to appear when a fetch call has been successfully made to an API. I'm using redux with thunk to make fetch it and it changes the state of a prop called loading to true/false and an error prop to null/the error in string format. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please add code examples so that we can better understand? Thunk is a great solution for handling side effects, so you're probably very close to your solution.

Comment: Yeah, how are your notifications handled? We handle ours in redux (all of our toast notifications are part of the store) so, whenever the async part of the thunk runs, we just dispatch an action inside the same thunk with a notification action (success or error). This works really well for simple and straightforward setups, anything more complex and you'll have to look into effects middleware.

Comment: @Adam Yes, that is exactly the way I'm doing it but the problem is that I can't figure how to fire off the function for the notification when the fetch success action is dispatched. The initial approach for me seemed to have a "notificationSuccess" state in redux (which I'm obviously mapping to props in my react component) that switches between true/false. But that won't work because it's impossible to distinguish the state changes from the actual fetch success. Sorry if I'm bad at explaining my problem I appreciate your help!

Comment: @BEVR1337 it is similar to that of Effaunels code (in his answer)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an additional field which would inform the component that the fetch has ended. For example, in your `dispatch(fetchSuccess(...))` which sets loading to false, you could add a message field in one of the **reducers**:

```js
...
switch(action.type){
   case FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, data: action.payload, loading: false, message: 'success'}
...
}
```

It doesn't really matter what that is. If you API sends back a `statusCode: 200` success response, you could use that as a message.

Another alternative is to create a *selector* and watch for a specific `data: action.payload` change.

P.S.: If your notification handling is done through a separate redux reducer, you can do that as well:

```js
...
try{
   dispatch(fetchLoading())
   ...
   const response = await axios.get(...)
   const data = response.data
   ...
   dispatch(fetchSuccess(data))
   disaptch(openNotification())
} catch(error){
   dispatch(fetchError(error.message))
}
...
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the way I'm doing it but the problem is that I can't figure how to fire off the function for the notification when the fetch success action is dispatched. The initial approach for me seemed to have a "notificationSuccess" state in redux (which I'm obviously mapping to props in my react component) that switches between true/false. But that won't work because it's impossible to distinguish the state changes from the actual fetch success. Sorry if I'm bad at explaining my problem I appreciate your help!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you need to have a propsChanged listener in your component. Using React Hooks, **useEffect** would be a great place for that. If you still use components,**static getDerivedStateFromProps** should also work. Just check the props with if statement, then **dispatch(openNotification())** from there.

Comment: To fire off the function for the notification when the fetch success action is dispatched you  could add a middleware, which would check for the action type and trigger a function based on that. It is a very common approach in redux. In fact, it is one of the best ones